# Is it possible to create a law of probability in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of probability and I want to sample one component from this vector  by taking into account the value of its probability.
Here is an example:

```
x = [1/2,1/4,1/4]
```

The probability of taking 1 in x is 1/2, the probability for 2 and 3 is 1/4. How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample` function

```
sample(1:3, 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25))
```

It selects one value from `c(1, 2, 3)` with the probability of `c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25)` respectively. 
Read `?sample` for more details on how it works.